# Make @SpringBootTest use a new application on every test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, applicationcontext

Is there any way to make Spring boot use a completely fresh `ApplicationContext` on every single `@Test` method execution and discard the previous application context ?

Anyway to change the [default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181188/7134737) of reusing `ApplicationContext` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate a test method with `@DirtiesContext` to indicate the `ApplicationContext` after running this test method is dirty such that when it executes the next test method , it will completely refresh the `ApplicationContext` :

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test1() {

    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test2() {

    }

}
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: I have added another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/70946757/7134737